# PhoneGap and Streaming Audio?

Tags: cordova, audio-streaming

I'm going to rewrite an existing native BlackBerry Internet radio application for Nokia models using PhoneGap and would like to know whether PhoneGap supports play of streaming media?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this feature is not supported in the current Phonegap version for Symbian devices: http://phonegap.com/about/feature/